# How to change the value of a substring?

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

I'm trying to make a classic hangman program(the GUI is fine, no problem with it), where the user guesses one letter at a time. The problem is, when the user guesses a letter, it replaces the place of " _ " with the letter guessed(if the letter is in the word), but when the next letter is guessed, it forgets about the last guess, and the place goes back to " _ ". Sorry if that's unclear, here's an example

```
Word is tiger,  
user guesses "g",  
outputs _ _ g _ _,  
user guesses "r",  
outputs _ _ _ _ r.
```

How I want the code to work:

```
Word is tiger,  
user guesses "g",  
outputs _ _ g _ _,  
user guesses "r",  
outputs _ _ g _ r.
```

How can I achieve this? Keep in mind that tiger was just an example word, words are pulled randomly from an array. I think the only way to do this is to change the value of the substring in blanks, but I don't know how to do this. As of now, the user guesses the letter from the GUI window(where the man himself is) and submits the answer by pressing a button. The output is just printed on console for now.

Here's the troublesome part of the program:

```
// guess is the name of JTextPane next to button
// randWord is the word pulled randomly from an array
private void guessLetter() {
    guessedLetter = guess.getText();
    if (randWord.contains(guessedLetter)){
        reveal(); // method below
    } else {
        wrongGuesses++; // when wrongGuesses adds,
        update(); // another body part is added, method not below
    }
}

private void reveal() {
    int start = randWord.indexOf(guessedLetter); //gets the index of the letter guessed
    String print = blanks.substring(0, start) + guessedLetter + blanks.substring(start+1); //reveals the letter
    System.out.println(print);//prints the revealed letter in correct spot
}
```

Comment: save already `guessedLetter`s inside blanks?

Comment: You should try to narrow down your question.  I think a full solution would require at least 50-100 lines of Java code, which is a bit too broad for a single answer.

Comment: @d9ngle pretty much. I want the substring of `blanks` to hold the value of the `guessedLetter` if it is correct. look at my example in the post :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm just asking if there is a way to change the value of a substring. Shouldn't that only take a few lines?

Comment: I already know that line 3 of `reveal()` method needs to be changed, but I don't know what to change it to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to approach this is to maintain a `StringBuilder` object which would be updated during each guess of a letter.

```
String wordToGuess = "tiger";
StringBuilder wordToShow = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i < wordToGuess.length(); ++i) {
    wordToShow.append("_");
}

// update publicly shown string; return true if one or more matches found,
// otherwise return false
public boolean guessLetter(char letter) {
    boolean result = false;
    for (int i=0; i < wordToGuess.length(); ++i) {
        if (wordToGuess.charAt(i) == letter) {
            // reveal the correctly guessed character
            wordToShow.setCharAt(i, letter);
            result = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public String reveal() {
    return wordToShow.toString();
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but this is a lot of changing to do in my program. Is there a similar way to do this without using char? I would rather stick to Strings, but if i can't that's OK. Quick, helpful answer. :)

Comment: If your user is really entering one character at a time, then `char` is the primitive type which would seem to make the most sense to use here.  The difference in my approach is that the `reveal()` method has now been reduced to basically just returning a string; the real logic happens each time a user makes a guess.  You are free to use whatever you wish.

Comment: But your variable `wordToShow` is like my variable `blanks` in this case, which holds many underscores(as many as the length of the word). Does that make `wordToShow.setCharAt(i, letter);` impossible, if `wordToShow` is a string? This sounds very dumb, but can a char hold more than 1 character like a string can?

Comment: Strings in Java are _immutable_, meaning once you create them, you can't change them (sort of like SAT scores).  Use a `StringBuilder` instead to flip the underscores into characters for each successful guess.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by _flip the underscores_?

Comment: I mean replace the underscores with characters, that's all.

Comment: OK that makes more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into consideration what you want to do when a word contains a letter multiple times :

```
guessedSoFar = reveal(guessedSoFar, randWord, guessedLetter);

private String reveal(String guessedSoFar, String randWord, char letter) {

    String newString = "";

    for (int i = 0 ; i < randWord.length(); i++) {
        if (randWord.charAt(i) == letter && guessedSoFar.charAt(i) == '_')
            newString += randWord.charAt(i);
        else 
            newString += guessedSoFar.charAt(i);
    }

    return newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a private variable(I named mine `currentWord`), and set it equal to `blanks`. Then you need to make some minor modifications to your code:

```
public class Hangman extends JFrame {
    private String currentWord;
    //when "blanks" gets assigned a value, make "currentWord" equal to it   
    //... 
    //...
private void guessLetter() {
    guessedLetter = guess.getText();
    if (randWord.contains(guessedLetter)){
        reveal();
    } else {
        wrongGuesses++;
        update();
    }
}

private void reveal() {
    int start = randWord.indexOf(guessedLetter);
    currentWord = currentWord.substring(0, start) + guessedLetter + currentWord.substring(start+1);
    System.out.println(currentWord);
    if (currentWord.equals(randWord)){
        System.out.println("You win!!");
    }
}
```

This will change `currentWord` one letter at a time, until you run out of guesses, or `currentWord` equals the original word. This works by changing one substring at a time, assigning `currentWord` to that value. Then that word is printed, changed with the next guess, printed, etc. until you win or lose.